# Implementar la libreria Zuck.js con CodeIgniter y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, librería

Buen día, quiero utilizar la librería Zuck.js para crear historias/estados como los de IG/FB/Whatsapp, para esto necesito tener la estructura del siguiente modo:

```
id: 'vision',
  photo: 'logo.jpg',
  name: 'nombreUsuario',
  link: 'enlace a su perfil',
  lastUpdated: 1492665454,
  items: [
    buildItem('id', 'tipo', duracion, 'ruta', '', false, 1492665454),
    buildItem('2', 'photo', 3, 'img/2.jpg', '', '', false, 1492665454),
    buildItem('3', 'photo', 3, 'img/3.jpg', '', '', false, 1492665454),
  ]
```

Yo guardo las fotos en una tabla que relaciona cada foto que se sube con un id de cada usuario. Al generar la consulta y generar un JSON los imprimo del siguiente modo:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "nick": "milf",
    "ruta": "IMG-20160215-WA0017.jpeg",
    "fecha": "2019-08-02 03:11:18",
    "tipo": "3",
    "usuario": "12"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "nick": "kata",
    "ruta": "IMG-20160409-WA0060.jpg",
    "fecha": "2019-08-02 04:15:00",
    "tipo": "3",
    "usuario": "11"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "nick": "milf",
    "ruta": "IMG-20160409-WA0062.jpg",
    "fecha": "2019-08-02 04:15:00",
    "tipo": "3",
    "usuario": "12"
}]
```

El inconveniente es que imprimo cada foto como una línea:
[image: Foto consulta MYSQL]

Y lo que necesito es mostrar todas de todos los usuarios, ejemplo: 
[image: Foto de ejemplo]

**O algún otro modo de imprimir la consulta para llenar los campos de la librería Zuck.js**

**Mi controlador**

```
public function historias(){

    $res = $this->Usuarios_model->historias();
    foreach ($res->result() as $row) {
        $datos[] = array(
            'id' => $row->idfotos,
            'nick' => $row->nick,
            'ruta' => $row->ruta,
            'fecha' => $row->fecReg,
            'tipo' => $row->tipo_foto,
            'usuario' => $row->idusuarios
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($datos);
}
```

**Mi modelo**

```
public function historias()
{   
    $sql = "SELECT usuarios.idusuarios, usuarios.nick, usuarios.fotoPerfil, fotos.idfotos, fotos.fecReg, fotos.tipo_foto, fotos.ruta
            FROM `usuarios`
            INNER JOIN fotos ON fotos.idusuarios = usuarios.idusuarios
            WHERE fotos.tipo_foto = 3";
    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

De antemano gracias por leer mi pregunta.

Comment: Hola, en que parte haces la consulta a la base de datos? en donde debes trabajar es en la consulta y la creación del json en la vista, ver el código del controlador y el modelo en esas partes podrían ser de ayuda.

Comment: Hola the-breaker, el modelo es básico, utilizo: la función es "return $this->db->get('fotos')" y en el controlador lo paso a JSON con json_encode();

Comment: Ya veo, lo mas adecuado para llenar el array de items no es crear varias columnas de rutas, existen otras opciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar en la consulta debes agrupar las fotografías por usuario, de modo que tengas cada uno con las una o mas fotos en un array, para esto se puede usar `group by` que agrupara las fotos según el `usuarios.idusuarios` y se puede usar `group_concat()` el cual agrupará cada dato de las columnas separandolas por ",".

**En el modelo**

```
public function historias()
{   
    $sql = "SELECT usuarios.idusuarios, usuarios.nick, usuarios.fotoPerfil,
            group_concat(fotos.idfotos) as idfotos, 
            group_concat(fotos.fecReg) as fecReg, 
            group_concat(fotos.tipo_foto) as tipo_foto, 
            group_concat(fotos.ruta) as fotos.ruta
            FROM `usuarios`
            INNER JOIN fotos ON fotos.idusuarios = usuarios.idusuarios
            WHERE fotos.tipo_foto = 3
            group by usuarios.idusuarios";
    return $this->db->query($sql);   
 }
```

Luego en el controlador debes obtener los datos de las fotografías y colocarlos en un array que sera `$items`, para esto por cada usuario divides cada columna de la fotografia con `explode(',',$columna)`, que dan como resultado arrays con los que se llenará el campo 'items', que al final se envía en el array de `$datos`:

**En el controlador**

```
public function historias(){

    $res = $this->Usuarios_model->historias();
    foreach ($res->result() as $row) {
        $ids=explode(',',$row->idfotos);
        $rutas=explode(',',$row->ruta);
        $fechas=explode(',',$row->fecReg);
        $tipos=explode(',',$row->tipo_foto);
        $items=array();

        foreach ($ids as $key => $idfoto) {
            $items[$key]=array(
                'id'=>$idfoto,
                'ruta'=>$rutas[$key],
                'fecha'=>$fechas[$key],
                'tipo'=>$tipos[$key]
            );
        }
        $datos[] = array(
            'usuario' => $row->idusuarios,
            'nick' => $row->nick,
            'items' => $items
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($datos);
}
```

Por ultimo el resultado del json quedaria de la forma:

```
[{
    "usuario": "12",
    "nick": "milf",
    "items": [{
        "id": "1",
        "ruta": "IMG-20160215-WA0017.jpeg",
        "fecha": "2019-08-02 03:11:18",
        "tipo": "3"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "ruta": "IMG-20160409-WA0062.jpg",
        "fecha": "2019-08-02 04:15:00",
        "tipo": "3"
    }]
}, {
    "usuario": "11",
    "nick": "kata",
    "items": [{
        "id": "5",
        "ruta": "IMG-20160409-WA0060.jpg",
        "fecha": "2019-08-02 04:15:00",
        "tipo": "3"
    }]
}]
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.